# Zend Framework 2: upload and rename multiple files

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a Zend Form and offer the option to upload multiple files with the form. I use dropzone.js. When I upload a single file, everything works fine, I get the Post data and the file gets renamed and moved into the correct folder, but as soon I upload 2 files, I get an Error Message: **Notice: Array to string conversion** which points to $upload->addFilters('File\Rename'.....

What am I doing wrong here? I have everything in a foreach loop, should this not solve the issue? I can not find a solution for it. Anyone got a tip for me?

Here my Sourcecode so far:

```
    $upload = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

    // Limit the amount of files
    $upload->addValidator('Count', false, 2);

    // Limit the MIME type of all given files to gif and jpeg images
    $upload->addValidator('MimeType', false, array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg',));

    if (!$upload->isValid()) {
        $data = new JsonModel(array(
            'success' => "failed",
            'message' =>  "validation failed",
            ));
            return $data;

    }else{
         $files  = $upload->getFileInfo();
         $upload->setDestination('./public/uploads/tmp/');

         // loop through the file array
         foreach ($files as $file => $info)  {

           $file_ext = @strtolower(@strrchr($originalName,"."));                 
           $file_ext = @substr($file_ext, 1); // remove dot

           $newFilename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) .time(). '.' . $file_ext;

           $upload->addFilter('File\Rename', 
                    array('target' => $upload->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newFilename,
                   'overwrite' => true));

           if (!$upload->receive()) {
                $data = new JsonModel(array(
                                'success' => "upload failed",
                        ));
           }else{
                $data = new JsonModel(array(
                                'success' => "upload ok",                           
                        ));
           }
           return $data;
          } // end foreach
      }
```